# How to organize elements in array by their level?

Tags: typescript, algorithm, data-structures

For example, an array like this:

```
[1,2,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,1]
```

The value of each element is considered as its level.

Now I want to get an array like this:

```
[
  1: [2, 2: [3: [4]]],
  1: [2: [3: [4]]],
  1,
  1
]
```

The real elements are not a number, you can consider them as objects which have a property that can contain an array of their class.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @FarukHossain I'm using TypeScript, but I just want to find a way to solve this problem so there's no need for code. But if code makes answer more clear, use it as you wish.

Comment: 2 things. 1) Your expected output is not valid in any way 2) If you're dealing with some other structure show us a repesentation of that structure, not something completely over-simplified.

Comment: @Jamiec ok, in fact, every element is an Object like this: `{ level:number,contains:Object[] }`，and the lower-level element will be nested in `Object.contains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this version, the positive integer denotes the absolute depth of nesting:

```
def to_tree(x, index=0, depth=1):
   level = x[index]
   if depth < level:
       index, deeper = to_tree(x, index, depth + 1)
       return index, [deeper]
   so_far = [level]
   index += 1
   while index < len(x):
       #print(level, so_far, x[index:])
       this = x[index]
       if this == level:
           so_far.append(this)
       elif this > level:
           index, deeper = to_tree(x, index, depth + 1)
           so_far.append(deeper)
       elif this < level:
           index -=1
           break
       index += 1
   return index, so_far

from pprint import pprint

lst = [1,2,3,4,5, 1,5, 1,2,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,1]
_, answer = to_tree(lst)

pprint(answer, width=10)
```

### Output

```
[1,
 [2,
  [3,
   [4,
    [5]]]],
 1,
 [[[[5]]]],
 1,
 [2,
  2,
  [3,
   [4]]],
 1,
 [2,
  [3,
   [4]]],
 1,
 1]
```

**Notice** how the abrupt transition of 1,5, puts the 5 at the same nesting depth as the preceding gradual 1,2,3,4,5 transition.

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_tree(x, index=0):
   level = x[index]
   so_far = [level]
   index += 1
   while index < len(x):
       #print(level, so_far, x[index:])
       this = x[index]
       if this == level:
           so_far.append(this)
       elif this > level:
           index, deeper = to_tree(x, index)
           so_far.append(deeper)
       elif this < level:
           index -=1
           break
       index += 1
   return index, so_far

from pprint import pprint

lst = [1,2,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,1]
_, answer = to_tree(lst)
assert answer == [1, [2, 2, [3, [4]]], 1, [2, [3, [4]]], 1, 1]

pprint(answer, width=10)
```